# How to check if a oracle database is compatible with REGEXP_LIKE?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to use the `Regexp_like` function in my oracle SQL queries, but no matter what I'm am trying I get the "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator" error. I have tried with regexp_like arguments from samples that should work, and simply changed the referenced field, and still it fails. The version is:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

However I suspect that some compatibility level is set so that the regexp_like function isn't supported. How can I check this?

Comment: Please show the query.

Comment: `regexp_like` is a condition, not a function. The message suggests you're using it wrong, but without the query we can't tell what you are doing.

Comment: When you hear hoofbeats, think of horses not zebras.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, actually I did find a ridiculous error. However now I'm getting another that actually suggest that my assumption might be right: I get: "ORA-00904: "REGEXP_LIKE": invalid identifier".

Comment: Fiddled a bit more and actually got it to work, which is great.

Comment: This question concerns a user error in the code which has not been posted.  So this question will not be of use to anybody else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I said in a comment, `regexp_like` is a condition not a function, so you can't compare it with a field. You should be doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM GLOBALDB.CUSTOMERS C
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(C.SHORT_NAME,'^CHRH$');
```

That is what is [shown in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm#i1048942).

Of course, since you're comparing the whole field, in this case you might as well do:

```
WHERE C.SHORT_NAME = 'CHRH';
```

Comment: I have a simple query and the regular expression is mentioned as your query in where condition but it gives invalid relational operator. My query is as below  select *
from student
where  
REGEXP_LIKE(student_name,'^RAJAN$');